# Stop express function after a reply has already been sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

im pretty new into .js and .ts and therefore also to express.js. I have the following lines of code:

```
    private post = async ( request: express.Request, response: express.Response, next:express.NextFunction) => 
{
    await this.myfunction(next) ? console.log("Do nothing") : console.log("end function/request/response");
    await this.anotherfunction();
    }
```

and my function looks like:

```
private myfunction = async (next: express.NextFunction): Promise<boolean> => {

let temp: boolean = false;

if(temp){
  return true;
} else {
  next(
      new HttpException(404, "just an example error")
    );
  return false;
}
```

HttpException function is build like in here: https://wanago.io/2018/12/17/typescript-express-error-handling-validation/

My Problem:
When I trigger my post function, this.myfunction will be executed and "function/request/response" will be printed in the console. After that this.anotherfunction() will be executed. But I want that if I get false as a return from this.myfunction that this.anotherfunction() wont be executed und my incoming request is stopped/cancelled, because I have already sent a response to my enduser in this.myfunction()

How do I do this?

Comment: So why don't you send back the response `res.send()`

Comment: I use the same error handling as: https://wanago.io/2018/12/17/typescript-express-error-handling-validation/
And this sends me a response.send

Answer (score 0):

Can you not simply do?

```
const result = await this.myfunction(next);
if(result) {
 await this.anotherfunction();
}
```

and better send `res.send` at the end.

Comment: Then I would have to put all my logic into the IF loop, and I think that's not nice.Maybe I can somehow check if a response has already been sent and if so then it should stop. The thing is that it takes a few ms to process and send my response from my HttpException

Comment: can you not simply do `return res.send()`? this will stop the execution

Comment: No I cant because I have already send a response in my HttpException function. I will get an error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client